# Significado de "condicionado"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado-en-contexto, chile

> **Ej1**: Cuando hay estadísticas que dicen que hace 5 años que un equipo no pierde contra otro cuando dirige determinado árbitro, eso les da vuelta en la cabeza a todos, incluso al mismo árbitro y entra **condicionado**.

¿Condicionado tiene el mismo significado de "sesgado", "prejuiciado" o va más bien por el lado de "influenciado", "tentado" o "instigado/inducido" a cumplir ese rol incluso testeando la inseguridad del aludido o para ver de que es capaz por las mismas circunstancias?

> Sesgado: Que no es objetivo o imparcial, sino que está **condicionado** por determinados intereses.

> Prejuiciado, da: 1. adj. Que está **influido** por algún prejuicio.

> prejuiciar: 1. tr. C. Rica, Cuba, Guat., Nic. y P. Rico. Predisponer a una persona en contra de alguien o de algo.

> Condicionar, hacer que algo dependa de alguna circunstancia en específico.1

> Instigado: Influir en una persona para que realice una acción o piense del modo que se desea, especialmente si es para que haga algo malo o perjudicial.

> **Ej2**: Dejé grabando el partido y lo ví sabiendo el resultado, ya un poquito **condicionado**.

> Condicionado: Que está restringido o limitado a ciertos requisitos.

> Supeditado es una conjugación del verbo supeditar, cuyo origen etimológico se halla en la lengua latina (suppeditāre). Supeditar, por su parte, refiere al acto de lograr la subordinación, el dominio o la sujeción de una cosa a algo diferente. Por ejemplo: “El acto está **supeditado** a las condiciones climáticas”, “El gobierno advirtió que el pago de los bonos se encuentra **supeditado** a la decisión judicial”, “El entrenador había **supeditado** el regreso de Gómez al equipo a que el jugador pidiera disculpas públicas a sus compañeros, algo que finalmente hizo anoche”.

Otro ejemplo, pero me interesan los dos primeros ejemplos(Ej1 y Ej2).

> **Ej3**: El problema se presenta cuando los tiempos de espera exceden un margen razonable que está **condicionado** por la gravedad, urgencia u oportunidad de la atención de salud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay veces que la mejor opción para entender una frase es intercambiar su contenido:

> Cuando hay estadísticas que dicen que hace 5 años que un equipo no pierde contra otro cuando dirige determinado árbitro, eso les da vuelta en la cabeza a todos, incluso al mismo árbitro y entra **condicionado**.

o

> El mismo árbitro entró al campo de juego con el **condicionante** de que las estadísticas dicen que hace cinco años que un equipo no pierde contra otro cuando dirige determinado árbitro.

o

> La **actitud condicionada** del árbitro puede deberse a que según las estadísticas un equipo no pierde contra otro desde hace cinco años cuando dirige determinado profesional.

o

> Las estadísticas dan vuelta en la cabeza a todos, incluso al mismo árbitro, y pueden **condicionar** su trabajo si mencionan que hace cinco años que un equipo no pierde contra el otro cuando dirige determinado sujeto.

Comment: Entonces para ti "condicionado" está mal? No es contra determinado árbitro, es contra él mismo. El partido todavía no ocurre, entra condicionado porque es un hecho de que hay demasiada coincidencia o el equipo ganador ha sido muy superior. Entra en la disyuntiva de ser más que "imparcial" favoreceriendo a un equipo(el siempre derrotado) para que el medio no lo siga desacreditando.

Comment: Exacto. En la frase la palabra *condicionado* es correcta. Es lo mismo que decir: – Juan leyó que los mariscos son muy indigestos por la noche, por lo que fue condicionado a la cena del restaurante en el puerto–. El árbitro está condicionado por lo que dicen las estadísticas y porque seguramente se refieren a él como persona que participó en esos partidos.